# Font-awesome Less CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

I am using font-awesome less to compile less files the problem i have is about less classes in font-awesome.
In my html i have

```
<i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" title="View"></i>
```

What i need i to get something like this

```
<i class="view" title="View"></i>
```

And to meke a less class like this

```
i.view{
 .fa; 
 .fa-eye; 
 .fa-lg;
}
```

But it does not work correct, compile is not possbile.

UPDATE
Only way to make it was like this

```
i.view{
    .fa; 
    .fa-lg;
&:before{
        content:@fa-var-eye;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you compile? Any error?

Comment: It says only for .fa-eye is not defined

Answer (score 1):

http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

```
i.view{
 &:extend(.fa); 
 &:extend(.fa-eye); 
 &:extend(.fa-lg);
}
```

Comment: Already tried does not work :(

Comment: Why does that not work? Try using the `all` keyword with your extends, which also extends the nested pseudo classes. See http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extend-all-

Comment: I alredy extedne my main.less with all less needed